# Unity 5 - Shoot up, Nave inimiga nao atira

Tags: c#, unity3d

A nave inimiga simplesmente não consegue atirar e andar ao mesmo tempo, ou ele faz uma coisa ou outra.

```
    public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 5f;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Vector2 min = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0,0));

        transform.Translate (new Vector3(0,1,0) * speed* Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.y < min.y) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}



    ublic class EnemyGunScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject HitL;
    public GameObject HitR;
    public GameObject EnemyBullet;
    public float nextFire = 1f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Invoke("FireEnemyBullet", 1f);
    }

    void FireEnemyBullet(){

        GameObject playerShip = GameObject.Find ("Player");

        if (playerShip != null && Time.time*3 >= nextFire) {

            GameObject bullet01 = (GameObject)Instantiate (EnemyBullet);
            bullet01.transform.position = HitL.transform.position;

            GameObject bullet02 = (GameObject)Instantiate (EnemyBullet);
            bullet02.transform.position = HitR.transform.position;

            //Vector2 direction = playerShip.transform.position - bullet.transform.position;

            //bullet01.GetComponent<EnemyBullet>().SetDirection(direction);

            //nextFire += Time.time/3;

            nextFire += 1.5f;

        } 

    }


}
```

Eu criei um `GameObject` chamado `gun` e dentro dele criei mais dois o `hitR` e `hitL` q é da onde sai os tiros, o script `EnemyGunScript` está no `gun` e o `gun` na nave inimiga. Por favor me ajudem, se souber uma possivel solução em javascript tmb serve.

Comment: Não entendi, o código ta em c# mas você quer a solução em javascript???

Comment: Se alguém souber alguma possivel solução serve, independentemente se for em C# ou JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, da forma que construiu seu script ficou meio que complicado de funcionar mesmo, da forma que você apresentou o código da pra entender que a classe nunca foi chamada!

Outro detalhe é que você construiu uma classe inimigo:

```
public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour {
```

E tambem construiu uma outra classe para o inimigo atirar:

```
public class EnemyGunScript : MonoBehaviour {
```

Ficou sem nexo a classe que faz o inimigo atirar não possuir uma nave!
O ideal é você fazer uma mesclagem das 2 classes, logico, fundindo a classe `EnemyGunScript` na classe `EnemyScript` fazendo com que `EnemyGunScript` se torne um metodo dentro da classe `EnemyScript`!

Dessa forma fica mais organizado e sempre facilitando a manutenção, outro detalhe dessa abordagem é que você tera tudo em um só lugar: HP do inimigo, munição, poderes especiais etc...

Comment: Adicional sem editar a resposta, digo para mesclar pois você esta chamando EnemyGunScript em dois objetos, fazendo duas chamadas no evento Update e uma chamada no update para a nave andar, ou seja, você tem 3 Updates basicamente no mesmo Objeto, por isto você anda ou atira!

Comment: Deu certo, agora eu só tenho que ajustar algumas coisas, obrigada

Comment: ;D tranquilo, é assim q funciona!